# Can I safely free up this kitchen countertop hole?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher, kitchen-sink

Our kitchen sink has an extra faucet hole, where I'd like to install a small tap for filtered water. But there is a stub of some old fixture in the hole. (I don't know what this thing is so I am just calling it 'the junk item')

[image: Junk in unused hole]

When I look underneath, I see that the grey drain hose from the dishwasher is attached to this junk, as is the black hose that leads to the garbage disposal.

Front view:

[image: Front view]

Upward view:
[image: Upward view]

I understand having a big loop in the drain prevents backflow and odors, and I guess attaching the hose-joint under the countertop keeps it well elevated. But could I move the joint all the way inside the cabinet instead, to free up that hole for a new faucet?

For example could I attach it to the back wall, just beneath the countertop?
This looks really simple but I have zero plumbing experience; what are the potential pitfalls here?

Not sure if I'm using the right vocabulary here, but hopefully the annotated pictures make it clear if the words aren't. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure that's a vent for the dishwasher.   I wouldn't mess with it..somebody in the past musta determined it was needed.

Comment: That's a fully functional air gap, not "a junk item" nor a "stub of an old fixture."

Comment: If you have a soap dispenser on the other side, there are combination air gap/soap dispensers out there. That said, the few I’ve seen are pretty blocky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [air gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_(plumbing)). There are two ways to prevent backflow of sewage from a dishwasher - a "high loop" and an air gap.

Generally speaking, older installations have traditional air gaps and newer ones use a high loop. But as I understand it, *some* jurisdictions may require a traditional air gap. If yours allows a high loop, then you should be able to:

- Remove the black hose.
- Connect the dishwasher hose directly to the disposal - you may need [an adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_(plumbing)) which normally comes with the disposal and/or dishwasher.
- Mount the hose so that the loop goes as high as possible, but at a minimum above the bottom of the sink.

Once you do that, you can use the hole for other purposes.